# Quarto/revealjs vertical slides with sectionin

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

In Quarto, revealjs presentations can have sections:

```
---
format: revealjs
---

# Section 1

## Slide 1
Slide 1 content

## Slide 2
Slide 2 content
```

It is also possible to stack slides vertically, but then the horizontal slides must have the first heading level:

```
---
format:
    revealjs:
        navigation-mode: vertical
---

# Slide 1
Slide 1 content

## Slide 1.1
Slide 1.1 content

# Slide 2
Slide 2 content
```

Is there a way to have *both* sectioning and vertical slides? One could use a slide with only the title as section header, but the graphical result is not optimal.

EDIT: I also noticed that when using first-level heading for slides, the .scrollable option does not work on horizontal slides, but only on vertical slides. Is it possible to have *both* vertical slides and scrollable horizontal slides?

What I would like to have is:

```
---
format:
    revealjs:
        navigation-mode: vertical
---

# Section 1

## Slide 1
This is the first horizontal slide

## Slide 2
This is the second horizontal slide

### Slide 2.1
This should be a vertical slide under the second horizontal slide, but does not work

## Slide 3 {.scrollable}
This should be a scrollable slide but does not work
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that you are trying to render (even though it is not working). I am actually confused :-)

Comment: I edited the post showing what I would like to do. What I would like to have is sections (first-level heading), horizontal slides (second-level heading), *and* vertical slides (third-level sectioning). I may need the horizontal slides to be scrollable. I can't get vertical slides AND sectioning together, because vertical slides work only if the parent horizontal slide has a first-level heading.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to note,

- Firstly, I have used the option [`slide-level: 3`](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/presentations/revealjs.html#slides) so that, slides are created with level 3 (`###`) headings and level 2 headings can be used as section and horizontal slides when `navigation-mode: vertical` is used.
- Secondly, [`.scrollable` and `.smaller`](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/index.html#content-overflow) are slide level classes. Since I have used `slide-level: 3`, they won't work with two level headings (`##`). Instead, you can wrap the scrollable contents with pandoc divs (`:::`) and define a css class for that divs.
- Lastly, I have used `engine: knitr`, since a css chunk is used. And quarto tries to render a document with jupyter when it sees a css code chunk at the very first. So to avoid that, use `engine: knitr`.

````
---
format:
  revealjs:
    navigation-mode: vertical
    slide-level: 3
engine: knitr
---

## section 1

## Slide 1

This is the first horizontal slide


## Slide 2

This is the second horizontal slide

### Slide 2.1

This should be a vertical slide under the second horizontal slide

### Slide 2.2

This should be a vertical slide under the second horizontal slide


## Slide 3

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.scrollable {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

::: {.scrollable}

contents to be scrollable 

- Topic 2
   - Level 1
   - Level 2
   - Level 3
- Topic 3
   - Level 1
   - Level 2
   - Level 3
- Topic 4
   - Level 1
   - Level 2
   - Level 3
   
:::
````

Comment: In this way the section header is basically a slide with just  the tile, so it's like using the `slide-level: 2` and using first-level headings for slide titles. The `.scrollable` div doesn't seem to work, regardless of the level of the slide I apply it to.

Comment: Umm, did you try my code exactly as is and it is not working?

Comment: I cut and pasted in into Rstudio

Comment: @Claudio, it is weird. Because by running the same thing, I am getting the scrollbar on slide 3 and I have tested the code in both quarto versions 1.2.475 and 1.3.319.

Comment: I am lost at sea... I  had quarto 1.0 installed, so I upgraded it to 1.3.326. I checked it with `quarto check` and everything is fine (except I have no Jupyter installed). Pandoc is version 3.1.1. I tried to run your code from both RStudio and CLI with `quarto render test.qmd` and I still have no scrollbars in slide 3. Is there a way to debug the code? Just as an additional information, I am running it in LinuxUbuntu 22.04.

Comment: Well I have run this code on posit cloud, which is basically using ubuntu. So OS shouldn’t be an issue here.

Comment: So I cut and pasted your code above in posit.cloud, but I still get no scrollbars. See [here](https://ae100bd5545942228d77a77999a30c51.app.posit.cloud/p/6d5aaa6e/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253163/discussion-between-shafee-and-claudio).